# Convert Const3dPtr to a Vector3d in Gazebo (C++)

Tags: c++, ros

I have searched the internet for hours trying to find an answer, myabe you guys can help me?

I am trying to convert a Const3dPtr Pointer to a normal Vector3d variable in Gazebo.

Here is my Code:

```
private: void OnMsg(ConstVector3dPtr &_msg)
{
    ignition::math::Vector3 b = _msg;
    this->model->SetLinearVel(b);
}
```

Btw, im a newbie to c++, so its probably just something obvious.